# Horizontal scroll bar doesn't appear on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a Grid which has a TextBox inside a ScrollViewer:

```
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="271" Width="258">
                <Label FontSize="15" Margin="10"> Suggestions </Label>
                <Expander x:Name="expander" Margin="10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="5" />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" AcceptsReturn="True"
                AcceptsTab="True" FontSize="15"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Language="en-US"
                SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Even if I set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Visible, the horizontal scroll bar is not visible, and when I type some text that goes beyond the TextBox's width, I can't scroll:

[image]

Comment: Would a horizontal bar ever show if the text is wrapping?  Is't that the definition of wrapping?  To eliminate the need for the scrollbar?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04a77bd2-2218-4f39-87bc-c02b5d05452f/wpf-does-the-textblocktextwrappingwrapwithoverflow-work?forum=wpf .... the "linebreak" algorithm says it can't break your "dddddddddddddddd" sequence of text....but it's not causing the width of the textbox to be changed...thus no horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Think of it this way... You're telling something that requires a boundary to scroll "Hey, I want your content to wrap" so it says "ok cool, then I'm going to stop it at my edge, wrap it, and push vertical since you don't want it to go Horizontal past my edge" ...then you're plopping it in another ScrollViewer (of which there's already one built into the TextBox template) and that outer ScrollViewer is saying "uh, wtf do you want me to do with this dude? You already told my child to handle it." Right? I'd also be surprised that your GridSplitter works. Either ditch the wrapping, or accept it.

Comment: Oh and @tgeo is partially right, it's pushing it down because that outer scrollviewer is redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of the TextBox: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs#1473

it seems that this is the normal behavior: the horizontal scrollbar is not visible when TextWrapping is WrapWithOverflow.

Based on that, the only possible way to show the horizontal scrollbar of the TextBox is to set the TextWrapping to NoWrap.

A workarount to what (I think that) you want to achieve with the outer ScrollViewer might be:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" AcceptsReturn="True"
        AcceptsTab="True" FontSize="15"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Language="en-US"
        SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the TextBox element is not being entirely displayed. I'd bet that the scroll bar is there, you just cannot see it without re-sizing your current window or scrolling downwards in the main window.